# CSV Module to write new line data in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have list like the one below,

```
lista=["a","b","c","\n","d","e","f","\n","g","h","i","\n"]
```

Can some one please advise how I make csv module to write this so that every "\n" in the list is counted as a line break? To make it simpler the csv should look like this,

```
a,b,c

d,e,f

g,h,i
```

Please let me know if the question is not clear, I will make changes as required.

Comment: Your list is effectively a csv. Just use the join method to convert the list to a string and write to a file `with open('out.csv', 'wb') as outcsv; outcsv.write("".join(lista))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
import sys

def rows(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    while True:
        row = list(iter(it.next, '\n'))  # it.__next__ in Python 3.x
        if not row:
            break
        yield row

lista = ["a","b","c","\n","d","e","f","\n","g","h","i","\n"]
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)  # Replace sys.stdout with file object
writer.writerows(rows(lista))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the CSV module:

```
for s in ','.join(lista).split('\n'):
    print(s.strip(','), '\n')
```

This gives:

```
a,b,c

d,e,f

g,h,i
```